# Change XML element ordering while keeping structural hierarchy and attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I wish to change the order of some XML elements. The XML is complex and generated by a separate process - I am not fee to change it, so I was hoping to use XSLT to correct the element order.

I am not an XSLT expert(!) so I looked for some snippets and found something that, with minor changes to suit my case, *almost* works. The best version I have at present outputs elements in the correct order, but strips out all the attributes.

I created a simpler xml and corresponding xsl with the relevant features of my problem.

Here is the (dummy) example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Companies xmlns="company:fruit:ns" Version="1.0">
  <Description>Some example companies and fruit shipments</Description>
  <Company CompanyId="Acme">
    <Description>Some example shipments</Description>
    <Shipment Id="ABC">
      <Description>Some apples</Description>
      <Fruit>
        <Apples>10</Apples>
      </Fruit>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment Id="DEF">
      <Description>Some oranges and pears</Description>
      <Fruit>
        <Oranges>20</Oranges>
        <Pears>20</Pears>
      </Fruit>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment Id="JKL">
      <Description>Empty</Description>
      <Fruit/>
    </Shipment>
    <Fruit/>
  </Company>
  <Fruit/>
</Companies>
```

The problem is that there should be a Company-Fruit element following the Company-Description element (instead it follows all the Shipment elements) and there should be a Companies-Fruit element following the Companies-Description element (instead it follows all the Companies-company elements). I used the following xsl transformation to correct the element ordering:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="company:fruit:ns">
  <!-- See http://xsltbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/re-arrange-order-of-elements-in-xml.html -->
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" mode="copy"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Company/Description">
    <xsl:message>Matched Company Description</xsl:message>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" mode="copy"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../Fruit" mode="copy"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Companies/Description">
    <xsl:message>Matched Companies Description</xsl:message>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" mode="copy"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../Fruit" mode="copy"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Company/Fruit"/>
  <xsl:template match="Companies/Fruit"/>
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting xml has the right ordering but most of the attributes have been stripped out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Companies xmlns="company:fruit:ns">
   <Description>Some example companies and fruit shipments</Description>
   <Fruit/>
   <Company>
      <Description>Some example shipments</Description>
      <Fruit/>
      <Shipment>
         <Description>Some apples</Description>
         <Fruit>
            <Apples>10</Apples>
         </Fruit>
      </Shipment>
      <Shipment>
         <Description>Some oranges and pears</Description>
         <Fruit>
            <Apples>20</Apples>
            <Pears>20</Pears>
         </Fruit>
      </Shipment>
      <Shipment>
         <Description>Empty</Description>
         <Fruit/>
      </Shipment>
   </Company>
</Companies>
```

I would welcome any advice from the XSLT experts out there!

Comment: When you copy your element which has attributes, just copy those with a `<xsl:copy of-select="@*"/>`. This copies all attributes from the current node to the output position. Either you define another template like the one that matches `text()` or you put that command in your `<xsl:copy>` block in the copy-mode template.

Comment: @Matthias - thanks for your quick and helpful response. I tried making the changes you suggest, trying them in several places in the xsl, but generally it did not have the desired effect. I may have misunderstood your comment....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transformations that should keep nearly all the input unchanged are best started with the identity template.

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you override that template accordingly.

```
<!-- throw away <Fruit> elements, initially - they are handled separately -->
<xsl:template match="Company/Fruit | Companies/Fruit" />

<!-- re-build <Company> and <Companies> in the correct order -->
<xsl:template match="Company | Companies">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="Fruit" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And then you're done.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak for your very clear and helpful response. It's not working yet, unfortunately. The xslt processor complains of a runtime error in the identity transformation - saying that `An attribute node (Version) cannot be created after a child of the containing element`.

Comment: Wow, what XSLT processor are you using? o_O

Comment: A further - probably minor - issue might be that the `Fruit` element also appears in each `Shipment` and perhaps should not be thrown away. This is why my original xsl was more specific about what `Fruit` elements to discard.

Comment: I am using Saxon 9.5 (Home Edition) as my xslt processor. I should explain that the error occurs when the identity transformation is invoked, rather than saying that the identity transformation itself is at fault! Sorry for any confusion....

Comment: Ah I see where the error was. It was on my end, of course. Everything else would have scared me. Should work now.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak - you are a star! It works now and, even better, I understand why it works, based on the way your solution is structured. I will check that the solution works on my *real* problem - I am confident it should - and should then be able to mark the question as solved. Thanks again for your continued help :-)

Answer (score 3):

The solution by @Tomalak shows how to reorder elements such that, say, the `<Fruit>` elements under `<Company>` no longer follow the `<Shipment>` elements. However @Tomalak's solution puts the `<Fruit>` elements before the `<Description>` elements. The ordering should be `<Description>`,`<Fruit>`,`<Shipment>,...`.

Therefore for the sake of completeness, and to prove that I have learnt from @Tomalak's solution(!), the relevant parts of the complete version of the xsl are shown here:

```
<!-- throw away <Fruit> and <Description> elements, initially - they are handled separately -->
<xsl:template match="Company/Fruit | Companies/Fruit | Companies/Description | Company/Description"/>

<!-- re-build <Company> and <Companies> in the correct order -->
<xsl:template match="Company | Companies">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Description"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Fruit"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks again to @Tomalak for doing the heavy lifting...

Comment: Nice of you to also post your findings/own solution. Keep it up! :)