# XSL remove namespace on elements and for-each approach vs other best practices

Tags: xml, xslt, metadata, gis, xslt-2.0

I'm new to XSLT and I need to convert a geographical metadata XML file from one standard version (v3) to a newer one (v5).

There are several aspects to consider:

- Elements name are similar, but not identical, in v3 and v5.
- There are some elements on v5 that are not present in v3 and those have to be added anyway sometimes without values and sometimes with predefined attributes and values.
- On XML v5 all the elements must have a NS prefix such as `<gmd:...>`, `<gco:...>` that are not present in all the v3 elements.
- On my XML v5 output file **I don't want** the `xmlns` attribute on each element because it needs to be declared **only on the top of the file** (see result example).
- XML v3 input file has some kind of "legal value" so they must be took as-is.

All files have hundreds of lines so I posted here only portions of them.

This is a portion of a input file (XML v3):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\ISO19139_rve.xsl"?>
<MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd">
  <fileIdentifier>
    <gco:CharacterString>b0101011_Vincolo</gco:CharacterString>
  </fileIdentifier>
  <language>
    <gco:CharacterString>IT</gco:CharacterString>
  </language>
  <contact>
    <CI_ResponsibleParty>
      <organizationName>
        <gco:CharacterString>Comune di Conselve (capofila PATI)</gco:CharacterString>
      </organizationName>
      <role>
        <CI_RoleCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#CI_RoleCode" codeListValue="Autore">Autore</CI_RoleCode>
      </role>
      <contactInfo>
        <CI_Contact>
          <onlineResource>
            <CI_OnlineResource>
              <linkage>
                <URL>http://www.comune.conselve.it</URL>
              </linkage>
            </CI_OnlineResource>
          </onlineResource>
          <phone>
            <CI_Telephone>
              <voice>
                <gco:CharacterString>0499596511</gco:CharacterString>
              </voice>
            </CI_Telephone>
          </phone>
        </CI_Contact>
      </contactInfo>
    </CI_ResponsibleParty>
  </contact>
  <dateStamp>
    <gco:Date>2007-12-13</gco:Date>
  </dateStamp>
  <metadataStandardName>
    <gco:CharacterString>ISO 19115 (UNI EN ISO 19115) Repertorio Nazionale dei Dati Territoriali - Linee guida per l'applicazione dello standard ISO 19115</gco:CharacterString>
  </metadataStandardName>
  <metadataStandardVersion>
    <gco:CharacterString>2006 (v.0.3)</gco:CharacterString>
  </metadataStandardVersion>
  <identificationInfo>
    <MD_DataIdentification>
      <citation>
        <CI_Citation>
          <title>
            <gco:CharacterString>Ambiti sottoposti a regime di vincolo</gco:CharacterString>
          </title>
          <date>
            <CI_Date>
              <date>
                <gco:CharacterString>2007-12-13</gco:CharacterString>
              </date>
              <dateType>
                <CI_DateTypeCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="Creazione">Creazione</CI_DateTypeCode>
              </dateType>
            </CI_Date>
          </date>
          <identifier>
            <MD_Identifier>
              <code>
                <gco:CharacterString>b0101011_Vincolo.shp</gco:CharacterString>
              </code>
            </MD_Identifier>
          </identifier>
        </CI_Citation>
      </citation>
    </MD_DataIdentification>
  </identificationInfo>
</MD_Metadata>
```

This is the result structure I need (XML v5 structure):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\_stile metadati RVEN\xsl\Dataset - RNDT.xsl"?>
<gmd:MD_Metadata xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/gmd/gmd.xsd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <gmd:fileIdentifier>
    <gco:CharacterString>arpa_ve:c0408090_EQBfiumi</gco:CharacterString>
  </gmd:fileIdentifier>

  <gmd:language>
    <gmd:LanguageCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#LanguageCode" codeListValue="ita">ita</gmd:LanguageCode>
  </gmd:language>

  <gmd:characterSet>
    <gmd:MD_CharacterSetCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#MD_CharacterSetCode" codeListValue="utf8">utf8</gmd:MD_CharacterSetCode>
  </gmd:characterSet>

  <gmd:parentIdentifier>
    <gco:CharacterString>arpa_ve:c0408090_EQBfiumi</gco:CharacterString>
  </gmd:parentIdentifier>

  <gmd:hierarchyLevel>
    <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset">Dataset</gmd:MD_ScopeCode>
  </gmd:hierarchyLevel>

  <gmd:contact>
    <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
      <gmd:organisationName>
        <gco:CharacterString>ARPAV - Servizio Osservatorio Acque Interne</gco:CharacterString>
      </gmd:organisationName>

      <gmd:contactInfo>
        <gmd:CI_Contact>
          <gmd:phone>
            <gmd:CI_Telephone>
              <gmd:voice>
                <gco:CharacterString>+39 049 7393783</gco:CharacterString>
              </gmd:voice>
            </gmd:CI_Telephone>
          </gmd:phone>
          <gmd:address>
            <gmd:CI_Address>
              <gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                <gco:CharacterString>orac@arpa.veneto.it</gco:CharacterString>
              </gmd:electronicMailAddress>
            </gmd:CI_Address>
          </gmd:address>
          <gmd:onlineResource>
            <gmd:CI_OnlineResource>
              <gmd:linkage>
                <gmd:URL>http://www.arpa.veneto.it</gmd:URL>
              </gmd:linkage>
            </gmd:CI_OnlineResource>
          </gmd:onlineResource>
        </gmd:CI_Contact>
      </gmd:contactInfo>

      <gmd:role>
        <gmd:CI_RoleCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#CI_RoleCode" codeListValue="pointOfContact">Punto di contatto</gmd:CI_RoleCode>
      </gmd:role>
    </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
  </gmd:contact>

  <gmd:dateStamp>
    <gco:Date>2013-10-10</gco:Date>
  </gmd:dateStamp>

  <gmd:metadataStandardName>
    <gco:CharacterString>DM - Regole tecniche RNDT</gco:CharacterString>
  </gmd:metadataStandardName>

  <gmd:metadataStandardVersion>
    <gco:CharacterString>10 novembre 2011</gco:CharacterString>
  </gmd:metadataStandardVersion>

  <gmd:referenceSystemInfo>
    <gmd:MD_ReferenceSystem>
      <gmd:referenceSystemIdentifier>
        <gmd:RS_Identifier>
          <gmd:code>
            <gco:CharacterString>ROMA40/OVEST</gco:CharacterString>
          </gmd:code>
        </gmd:RS_Identifier>
      </gmd:referenceSystemIdentifier>
    </gmd:MD_ReferenceSystem>
  </gmd:referenceSystemInfo>


  <gmd:identificationInfo>
    <gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
      <gmd:citation>
        <gmd:CI_Citation>
          <gmd:title>
            <gco:CharacterString>EQB - Elementi di Qualità Biologica dei fiumi</gco:CharacterString>
          </gmd:title>
          <gmd:date>
            <gmd:CI_Date>
              <gmd:date>
                <gco:Date>2013-10-10</gco:Date>
              </gmd:date>
              <gmd:dateType>
                <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="creation">Creazione</gmd:CI_DateTypeCode>
              </gmd:dateType>
            </gmd:CI_Date>
          </gmd:date>
          <gmd:identifier>
            <gmd:RS_Identifier>
              <gmd:code>
                <gco:CharacterString>arpa_ve:c0408090_EQBfiumi</gco:CharacterString>
              </gmd:code>
            </gmd:RS_Identifier>
          </gmd:identifier>
        </gmd:CI_Citation>
      </gmd:citation>
    </gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
  </gmd:identificationInfo>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

This is my actual (only partially completed) XSL transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<!--Content:template xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"> -->
<!-- <?xml version="1.0"?> -->
<!-- <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\_stile metadati RVEN\xsl\Dataset - RNDT.xsl"?> -->
<!-- <xsl:element name="gmd:MD_Metadata" namespace="xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/gmd/gmd.xsd' xmlns:gco='http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco' xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2' xmlns:gmd='http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"> -->

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:element name="gmd:MD_Metadata">
      <xsl:element name="fileIdentifier">
         <xsl:element name="gco:CharacterString">
            <xsl:for-each select="//gmd:fileIdentifier">
               <xsl:value-of select="gco:CharacterString"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="gmd:language">
       <xsl:element name="gmd:LanguageCode">
          <xsl:attribute name="codeList">./resource/codeList.xml#LanguageCode</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="codeListValue">
             <!-- <xsl:for-each select="gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:language"> -->
             <xsl:for-each select="/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:language">
              <xsl:value-of select="gco:CharacterString"/>
           </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
     <xsl:for-each select="/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:language">
        <xsl:value-of select="gco:CharacterString"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>


    <xsl:element name="gmd:characterSet">
       <xsl:element name="gmd:MD_CharacterSetCode">
        <xsl:attribute name="codeList">./resource/codeList.xml#MD_CharacterSetCode</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="codeListValue">utf8</xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="gmd:parentIdentifier">
         <xsl:element name="gco:CharacterString"></xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="gmd:hierarchyLevel">
       <xsl:element name="gmd:MD_ScopeCode">
        <xsl:attribute name="codeList">./resource/codeList.xml#MD_ScopeCode</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="codeListValue"></xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="gmd:contact">
       <xsl:element name="gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty">
      <xsl:element name="gmd:organisationName">
        <xsl:element name="gco:CharacterString">
           <xsl:for-each select="gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:contact/gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty/gmd:organizationName"> <!-- [3] -->
                  <xsl:value-of select="gco:CharacterString"/>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="gmd:contactInfo">
        <xsl:element name="gmd:CI_Contact">
          <xsl:element name="gmd:phone">
            <xsl:element name="gmd:CI_Telephone">
              <xsl:element name="gmd:voice">
                <xsl:element name="gco:CharacterString">
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="gmd:address">
            <xsl:element name="gmd:CI_Address">
              <xsl:element name="gmd:electronicMailAddress">
                <xsl:element name="gco:CharacterString">
                   <xsl:for-each select="gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:contact/gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty/gmd:contactInfo/gmd:CI_Contact/gmd:phone/gmd:address/gmd:CI_Address/gmd:electronicMailAddress">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="gco:CharacterString"/>
                               </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="gmd:onlineResource">
            <xsl:element name="gmd:CI_OnlineResource">
              <xsl:element name="gmd:linkage">
                <xsl:element name="gmd:URL">
                   <xsl:for-each select="gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:contact/gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty/gmd:contactInfo/gmd:CI_Contact/gmd:phone/gmd:onlineResource/gmd:linkage">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="gco:CharacterString"/>
                               </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="gmd:role">
        <xsl:element name="gmd:CI_RoleCode">
           <xsl:attribute name="codeList">./resource/codeList.xml#CI_RoleCode</xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:attribute name="codeListValue">
              <xsl:for-each select="gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:contact/gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty/gmd:role/gmd:CI_RoleCode">
                     <xsl:value-of select="gco:CharacterString"/>
                  </xsl:for-each>
           </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the result I obtain applying my transformation (only a few lines):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd">
   <fileIdentifier>
      <gco:CharacterString xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco">b0101011_Vincolo</gco:CharacterString>
   </fileIdentifier>
   <gmd:language>
      <gmd:LanguageCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#LanguageCode" codeListValue="IT"/>IT</gmd:language>
   <gmd:characterSet>
      <gmd:MD_CharacterSetCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#MD_CharacterSetCode"
                               codeListValue="utf8"/>
   </gmd:characterSet>
   <gmd:parentIdentifier>
      <gco:CharacterString xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco"/>
   </gmd:parentIdentifier>
   <gmd:hierarchyLevel>
      <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue=""/>
   </gmd:hierarchyLevel>
   <gmd:contact>
      <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
         <gmd:organisationName>
            <gco:CharacterString xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco">Comune di Conselve (capofila PATI)</gco:CharacterString>
         </gmd:organisationName>
         <gmd:contactInfo>
            <gmd:CI_Contact>
               <gmd:phone>
                  <gmd:CI_Telephone>
                     <gmd:voice>
                        <gco:CharacterString xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco"/>
                     </gmd:voice>
                  </gmd:CI_Telephone>
               </gmd:phone>
               <gmd:address>
                  <gmd:CI_Address>
                     <gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                        <gco:CharacterString xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco"/>
                     </gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                  </gmd:CI_Address>
               </gmd:address>
               <gmd:onlineResource>
                  <gmd:CI_OnlineResource>
                     <gmd:linkage>
                        <gmd:URL/>
                     </gmd:linkage>
                  </gmd:CI_OnlineResource>
               </gmd:onlineResource>
            </gmd:CI_Contact>
         </gmd:contactInfo>
         <gmd:role>
            <gmd:CI_RoleCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#CI_RoleCode" codeListValue=""/>
         </gmd:role>
      </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
   </gmd:contact>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

As you can see I've the `xmlns:gxx="http://...` attribute repeated on each element and I don't want it.

Also, I know that my XSL approach is not the best. So if there's a better way (and I think so) to do this transformation with less coding and possibly less debug and maintenance efforts needed, I obviously will appreciate any suggestion!

For those who want to see the complete files there's [this ZIP archive](http://ul.to/dtdie5yo) that contains the 3 XML and my XSL.

Comment: As a general pointer: Don't obsess with where `xmlns` appears in your output or how the prefixes look like. This is *completely* irrelevant as long as the elements actually are in the right namespace.

Comment: In this case it is relevant since the XML must be validated and then imported into a Geonetwork database. My XML result file with `xmlns` attributes on each element doesn't pass the validation. And validation process is out of my control since it is defined by other organizations.

Comment: It will pass validation if elements are in the right namespace, no matter how that namespace is declared in the XML source.

Comment: Not sure but I can try. Anyway my actual problem is that the namespaces are added only on the single elements (see my result file) and not to the root `<gmd:MD_Metadata>` element (see the XML v5 structure example).
And about the for-each approach? Is it the only way?

Comment: No, that's not the only way. I'm in the process of writing an answer, it's a long one and it's gonna take a little while though. It would help if you sample v5 file would *exactly* reflect your sample v3 file, this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Thanks! This is a ZIP file containing all the complete files. [Metadata_XSL](http://ul.to/dtdie5yo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XSLT approach is *way* too complicated. XSLT is verbose, but not that verbose.

A few hints.

- Use proper namespace declarations. If most of your output needs to be in a certain namespace, put your stylesheet into that namespace by default. Declare:

  ```
  xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
  ```

  at the top level of your XSLT and your entire output will be in that namespace automatically except for nodes you declare otherwise.
- Don't use `<xsl:element>` if you want to create elements with a fixed name. Just write out the elements you want to create.

  ```
  <xsl:element name="gmd:MD_Metadata">
  </xsl:element>
  ```

  is equivalent to:

  ```
  <MD_Metadata>
  </MD_Metadata>
  ```

  if you used a default namespace like indicated above.
- The same goes for `<xsl:attribute>`. Just write it out.

  ```
  <xsl:element name="gmd:LanguageCode">
    <xsl:attribute name="codeList">./resource/codeList.xml#LanguageCode</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
  ```

  is

  ```
  <LanguageCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#LanguageCode">
  </LanguageCode>
  ```
- Use attribute value templates to fill attributes with calculated values:

  ```
  <LanguageCode codeListValue="{.}" />
  ```

  note the curly braces, into which you can put any XPath expression.
- Don't use `<xsl:for-each>` at all. Write templates and use `<xsl:apply-templates>`. Try to write short templates instead of cramming everything into one big `<xsl:template match="/">`.

---

This entire use-case is perfect for a "pull-style" approach.

- You don't really want to change much of your input. From all I can see, differences between v3 and v5 are marginal.
- Base your stylesheet on the identity template, handle only those cases where you actually need to make a change to the input.
- Think: *"If I find such a node is in the input, how should the output look like?"*.
- Write a template accordingly.
- Handle all nesting/recursion by calling `<xsl:apply-templates>`.
- It helps thinking your of input XML *flowing through* the stylesheet, like through a sieve. You don't *make* your stylesheet do stuff, you only set up case handlers.

This stylesheet is a good start:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" 
  xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco"
  xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd"
  xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

  <!-- default: all input nodes are copied as they are (identity template) -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- override: MD_Metadata needs to be rebuilt -->
  <xsl:template match="gmd:MD_Metadata">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

      <!-- handle fileIdentifier and language first -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="gmd:fileIdentifier | gmd:language" />

      <!-- now a few additions that are not in the source -->
      <characterSet>
        <MD_CharacterSetCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#MD_CharacterSetCode" codeListValue="utf8" />
      </characterSet>

      <parentIdentifier>
        <gco:CharacterString />
      </parentIdentifier>

      <hierarchyLevel>
        <MD_ScopeCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue="" />
      </hierarchyLevel>

      <!-- now handle the rest of the contents -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(
        self::gmd:fileIdentifier or 
        self::gmd:language
      )]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- override: the CharacterString beneath language becomes a LanguageCode -->
  <xsl:template match="gmd:language/gco:CharacterString">
    <LanguageCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#LanguageCode" codeListValue="{.}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </LanguageCode>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- add more overrides... -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note how the entire XSLT above does not concern itself with iteration or nesting. `<xsl:apply-templates>` always redirects to the identity template (or an override template you supplied). This way you need to build specific templates *only* for stuff that needs to change on its way from input to output.

The output looks like this:

```
<MD_Metadata xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd" xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <fileIdentifier>
    <gco:CharacterString>b0101011_Vincolo</gco:CharacterString>
  </fileIdentifier>

  <!-- ... and so on -->
</MD_Metadata>
```

If necessary, use empty templates to suppress unwanted output:

```
<xsl:template match="gmd:foo" />
<xsl:template match="gmd:bar" />
```

If you have a definitive list of changes from v3 to v5 you also have a list of override templates to create.

Comment: Your approach is obviously better than my... With so much patience I'm trying to write all the single templates. :-)
Looking on the standard v5 that I need to get, there's also a elements order problem that I didn't notice before.

E.g.: look at the `<gmd:contact>` element. There's a `<gmd:role>` sub-element that is positioned **after** `<gmd:contactInfo>`, but on my source v3 file, the `<role>` sub-element appears **before** the `<contactInfo>`. How can I possibly change the order of specific sections/elements?

Comment: @RainbowCoder Sure, just write an override template for `gmd:contact` and re-order its contents manually, just like I did with `gmd:MD_Metadata`. Inside it you can simply call `<xsl:apply-templates select="...">` a few times to influence processing order.

Comment: I'm trying to rearrange the order of some nodes but I can't get what I want... I opened a new the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990118/xslt-change-xml-elements-order)

Comment: I saw your answer to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316865/change-xml-element-ordering-while-keeping-structural-hierarchy-and-attributes) but I can't reproduce it on my transformation to get the desired result.

Comment: @RainbowCoder That's because you made a typo, basically. ;) I've answered your followup-question in the other thread.