# XSLT Can't match element with specific namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, uppercase

I have this XML source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\ISO19139_rve.xsl"?>
<MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd">
    <identificationInfo>
        <MD_DataIdentification>    
            <extent>
                <EX_Extent>
                    <geographicElement>
                        <EX_GeographicExtent>
                            <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                                <westBoundLongitude>
                                    <gco:Decimal>1</gco:Decimal>
                                </westBoundLongitude>
                                <eastBoundLongitude>
                                    <gco:Decimal>2</gco:Decimal>
                                </eastBoundLongitude>
                                <southBoundLatitude>
                                    <gco:Decimal>3</gco:Decimal>
                                </southBoundLatitude>
                                <northBoundLatitude>
                                    <gco:Decimal>4</gco:Decimal>
                                </northBoundLatitude>
                            </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                        </EX_GeographicExtent>
                    </geographicElement>
                    <temporalElement>
                        <EX_TemporalExtent>
                            <extent>
                                <gml:TimePeriod gml:id="tp1">
                                    <gml:begin>
                                        <gml:TimeIstant gml:id="ti1">
                                            <gml:timePosition>2007-12-01</gml:timePosition>
                                        </gml:TimeIstant>
                                    </gml:begin>
                                    <gml:end>
                                        <gml:TimeIstant gml:id="ti2">
                                            <gml:timePosition>2010-01-01</gml:timePosition>
                                        </gml:TimeIstant>
                                    </gml:end>
                                </gml:TimePeriod>
                            </extent>
                        </EX_TemporalExtent>
                    </temporalElement>
                </EX_Extent>
            </extent>
        </MD_DataIdentification>
    </identificationInfo>
</MD_Metadata>
```

And I need to replace the  block with this simple one:

```
...
<gml:TimePeriod gml:id="TP1">
    <gml:beginPosition>2007-12-01</gml:beginPosition>
    <gml:endPosition>2010-01-01</gml:endPosition>
</gml:TimePeriod>
...
```

This is my transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco"
    xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd"
    xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd"
    >

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="gml:TimePeriod">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <beginPosition>
                <xsl:value-of select="gml:begin/gml:TimeIstant/gml:timePosition"/>
            </beginPosition>
            <endPosition>
                <xsl:value-of select="gml:end/gml:TimeIstant/gml:timePosition"/>
            </endPosition>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There's the `xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"` declaration on the top of the stylesheet but I think it's a matter of namespace.
If I put a break point near the

`<xsl:template match="gml:TimePeriod" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">`

line, I never enter inside that code.
It seems that if I need to go through `<gmd:...>` elements, all works fine, but when I need to reach a `<gml:...>` (or any other different from gmd) element, it doesn't match.

**-- UPDATED on 2014-04-15 --**

I forgot to specify that I also need to convert to UPPER-CASE the `"tp1"` attribute value of `<gml:TimePeriod gml:id="tp1">` element. What do I need to change on my actual transformation?

Comment: You declare `xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"` in your XSLT but `xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"` in your XML. Of course your template cannot match when the namespace URIs differ.

Comment: Oh... you never stop learning! :-D
Thanks!

Comment: Namespaces in XML are just like namespaces in any programming language. They *actually are part of the node name*, even if hidden by convenience facilities like namespace prefixes or default namespaces. A slightly different namespace URI makes a completely different node.

Comment: Again about namespaces... On each `<xsl:template>` definition on my transformation, I use the attribute `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"` that avoids the ns declaration on every element but also removes the element prefixes. Is there a way to maintain the ns prefix on all elements (such as `<gmd:...>`, `<gco:...>`, etc.) but without reporting the `xmlns="http://..."` attribute specification on each of them?

Comment: Usually `exclude-result-prefixes` is used on `<xsl:stylesheet>` nowhere else. And as I said in one of your earlier posts: Don't obsess with the prefix. As long as the element is in the right namespace (by means of a default namespace) the prefix is irrelevant. No correctly implemented tool will ever require that namespace prefixes look a certain way as long as the namespaces themselves are correct.

Comment: @Tomalak I added a question about this block of XML. I forgot to mention that I need to convert the attribute value to UPPER-CASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tomalak mentions in the comments, the root cause of your problem is that you have different namespace URIs mapped to the `gml` prefix in your input XML and in your stylesheet, so the elements in your XML and the elements that the XSLT is looking to match are not considered the same.

Regarding your addition:

> I forgot to specify that I also need to convert to UPPER-CASE the "tp1" attribute value of `<gml:TimePeriod gml:id="tp1">` element. What do I need to change on my actual transformation?

this should just be a matter of adding one extra template (once you've got the namespaces aligned) and using the XPath 2.0 `upper-case` function:

```
<xsl:template match="gml:TimePeriod/@gml:id">
  <xsl:attribute name="gml:id" select="upper-case(.)" />
</xsl:template>
```

This will affect only the ids of `gml:TimePeriod` elements, if you want to upper-case *all* the IDs then simply make it `match="@gml:id"` instead.

Comment: Perfect!
Yes, I updated the question but had already solved the namespace issue! Thanks!

Comment: @Rainbow It's worth noting that `<xsl:attribute name="{name()}">` would have worked as well (and it's more generic). Alternatively `<xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)" /></xsl:copy>`.